# What is the correct way to display nested uls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a nested sidebar menu for mobile.
When I click on the `span.big` I want the next ul to become visible.
So I call `.next()`.
Now the nested ul does show, however the problem is that the li below the doesn't move down under it, meaning that the ul is overlapping the li.

```
(function($) {
  $('.big').click(function() {
    $(this).next();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

How can i make the li move down correctly?

```js
    (function($) {

      $('.big').click(function() {
        $(this).next();
      });

    })(jQuery);
```

```css
#cssmenu {
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arvo, serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#cssmenu li {
  height: 50px;
}
#cssmenu ul>li {
  padding-top: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2)
}
#cssmenu ul>li>a {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#cssmenu ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu span.big {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -13px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
#cssmenu span:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-nav">
  <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
        <span class="big">+</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of the li is restricted so the submenu can't display properly.

Plus you aren't selecting anything with the JQuery `next` statement.

As mentioned in the comments, if a height is required for the `li`, you can substitute `min-height` for `height`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.big').click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arvo, serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#cssmenu >ul > li {
  min-height: 50px;
}
#cssmenu ul>li {
  padding-top: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2)
}
#cssmenu ul>li>a {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#cssmenu ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu span.big {
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -13px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
#cssmenu span:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-nav">
  <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
        <span class="big">+</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a side note, OP should use instead: `#cssmenu li {
  min-height: 50px;
}`  or maybe `#cssmenu > ul > li {
   min-height: 50px;
}` dpending expected behaviour

Comment: Yeah, I thought that but didn't want to complicate it...but it's worth editing in.

Answer (score 1):

in jQuery, `next()` is just used to select the next sibling of an element.
That means your javascript code isn't doing anything as you're not using the result of `next()`

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6yesewh9/

the fix was changing your li css `height` to `min-height`

```
#cssmenu li{
    min-height:50px;
}
```

Also I changed your `.next` to use .siblings` in your jQuery code